# Link two models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models: Profile and Course.
Profile stores user info. Course has a title, description and date.
User can sign up for the course using link. My goal is to make a list of users, who belong to each course.

I tried using ForeignKey, but i need to have user added to the list only after he signs up for it.

```
class Course(models.Model):
course_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
course_description = models.TextField()
course_published = models.DateTimeField("date published", default = datetime.now())
course_users = []
def __str__(self):
    return self.course_title

def course_signup(request):
# here i guess i need to somehow add the user to the list
Course.course_users.append(Profile.id)
return redirect("main:homepage")
```

Profile code:

```
class Profile (models.Model):
user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image=models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='profile_pics')
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Profile,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
    img = Image.open(self.image.path)

    if img.height > 300 or img.width >300:
        output_size = (300,300)
        img.thumbnail(output_size)
        img.save(self.image.path)
```

I expect to have a list of users in Course.

Comment: you can add a many two many relationship check the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a many-to-many (m2m) relationship. You can either use the `ManyToMany()` part of Django, or you could create your own relationship, like so:

```
class ProfileCourse(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
```

so then you can enroll a profile in a course with:

```
def course_signup(request):
     profile = [snip....]
     course = [snip...]
     ProfileCourse(profile=profile, course=course).save()
```

One of the real advantages of managing your own m2m relationships is that you can add additional information to the relationship. In this case, you might add "final_grade".

One more thing...m2m relationships are often simply named after the two sides of the relationship (e.g. ProfileCourse), *unless* there is another good word (e.g. "Enrollment") that exists to describe the relationship.